# Redirect subdomain without changing url in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(poodle|mandy|sandy|nova|wendy) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wendy/index.php#%1 [L]
```

here I am able to redirect all folders without changing url.

But when I am trying to go redirect subdomain

like

```
wendy.xxxxxx.com/ggsgs/sfghdsgd.html
```

I am getting Internal Server error.

any way I can redirect all subdomains to wendy/index.php without changing url.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can rewrite to hash fragments (`#...`). Why are you doing that anyway? That's for the browser. Rather rewrite to a query string.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't manage domains redirection in .htaccess. It should be configured in apache config using VirtualHosts like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  Servername name1 
  ServerAlias name2
  ServerAlias name3

  [...]

</Virtualhost>
```

If you want to redirect ANY sub domain, you can use wildcard:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```